# QGIS MongoDB Plugins

Tags: mongodb, plugins, qgis

I am currently trying to use the QGIS plugins to connect MongoDB such as MongoConnector and Load MongoDB Layers. But I couldn´t make it work.

Is there anybody, who uses those plugins or are they broken? 
Here is the error I got for  Load MongoDB Layers plugin

```
 Couldn't load plugin qgis-mongodb-loader due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 219, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/nilci_000/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis-mongodb-loader\__init__.py", line 28, in classFactory
    from .loadMongoDB import loadMongoDB
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/nilci_000/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis-mongodb-loader\loadMongoDB.py", line 16, in 
    from loadMongoDB_dialog import loadMongoDBDialog
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/nilci_000/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis-mongodb-loader\loadMongoDB_dialog.py", line 32, in 
    QMessageBox.critical(iface.mainWindow(),
NameError: name 'iface' is not defined


Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

And this is for MongoConnector plugin

```
Couldn't load plugin MongoConnector due to an error when calling its classFactory() method


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 219, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/nilci_000/.qgis2/python/plugins\MongoConnector\__init__.py", line 26, in classFactory
    from MongoConnector.plugin import MongoConnectorPlugin
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/nilci_000/.qgis2/python/plugins\MongoConnector\plugin.py", line 25, in 
    from connect_action import ConnectAction
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/nilci_000/.qgis2/python/plugins\MongoConnector\connect_action.py", line 29, in 
    from pymongo import MongoClient
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named pymongo


Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Best,
Nilü

Comment: See this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33722219/2553539), already resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before installing MongoConnector Plugin make sure you have "pymongo" installed in your python. Python and Mongo speak with each other using this.

You can install it from their [official link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/2.7.2#downloads).

It is also mentioned in Mongo Connector page that pymongo should be > 3.0 
So it will not work with python 2.7
Ref: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/MongoConnector/

After that try installing that plugin again.